# Time information is missing when converting LocalDate to java.util.Date

Tags: java, date, java-8, localdate

Time information is missing when converting LocalDate to java.util.Date

My input date is in the format "2019-08-30T19:47:22+00:00"  (String). I have to convert it to java.util.Data. I would like to do it using java 8.

```
String input = "2019-08-30T19:47:22+00:00";
Date date = null;
LocalDate dateTime = LocalDate.parse(input, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
date = Date.from(dateTime.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
System.out.println("Parsed from LoacalDate: " + date);
System.out.println("From new Date(): " + new Date());
```

**Output**

- Parsed from LoacalDate: Fri Aug 30 **00:00:00** CDT 2019 From new
- Date(): Fri Aug 30 17:16:23 CDT 2019

In the output time information is missing. How to get time information?

Comment: `LocalDate` doesn't have a time. Look at `LocalDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` if you need time. But I'm curious what you thought `dateTime.atStartOfDay()` does.

Comment: What does the javadoc of LocalDate say about that class? What does it represent?

Comment: Side question: Why do you have to convert it to `java.util.Date`?  `java.time` has been out for 5 years now - are you working with an older API?  A lot of stuff has managed to switch over, especially ORMs.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I am using a library. It expects the date in java.util.Date

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

`LocalDate` stores only a date, so wrong class to use.

```
java.util.Date                              // Terrible class, now legacy. Avoid. Replaced by `java.time.Instant` in JSR 310. Use only where required, to interoperate with old code not yet updated for java.time.
.from(                                      // Convert from modern `Instant` to legacy `Date`.
    OffsetDateTime                          // The modern class to represent a moment in the context of an offset-from-UTC (a number of hours-minutes-seconds). Not to be confused with a time zone, which is a history of changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. 
    .parse( "2019-08-30T19:47:22+00:00" )   // Parse text into an `OffsetDateTime` object.
    .toInstant()                            // Extract an `Instant`, a more basic building-block class that represent a moment in UTC (an offset of zero). 
)
.toString()                                 // Generates text representing the value of the `Date`. But this method lies! It dynamically applies your JVM’s current default time zone while generating the text.
```

Note that `java.util.Date::toString` tells a lie! That method dynamically applies the JVM’s current default time zone while generating the text to represent the value that is actually in UTC. One of many reasons to **never use this `Date` class**.

## Details

You are using the wrong classes.

### `LocalDate`

`LocalDate` represents a date only, no time-of-day, no time zone or offset.

By parsing your input representing a moment as simply a date, you are lopping off the time-of-day and the offset-from-UTC.

### `OffsetDateTime`

Your input `"2019-08-30T19:47:22+00:00"` represents a moment: a date, a time-of-day, an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. So parse that as a `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2019-08-30T19:47:22+00:00" ) ;
```

### Avoid legacy date-time classes

The `java.util.Date` class is *terrible*, and should no longer be used. It was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes as of the adoption of JSR 310.

However, if you must interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert back-and-forth. Look to new `to…`/`from…` methods added to the old classes.

The equivalent of `java.util.Date` is `java.time.Instant`, both representing a moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (though with a difference in resolution, milliseconds versus nanoseconds). So extract a basic `Instant` object from our more flexible `OffsetDateTime`.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
java.util.Date d = Date.from( instant ) ;
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to make it work using the following code snippet

```
  LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(input,DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
  date = Date.from(dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
  System.out.println("Parsed from LoacalDate:" + date);
  System.out.println("From new Date():" + new Date());
```

Comment: Thiagarajan Ramanathan, you’re throwing away the offset information from the string (+00:00) and substituting the offset of the JVM’s default time zone, in most cases leading to an incorrect result. Note that you don’t want a `Date` that prints as Fri Aug 30 19:47:22, but a `Date` that represents the same moment in time as the string.